# Google Sheet Change Font/Background Color Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am tring to fill a cell in google sheet with color using formulas/functions, I'm looking for functions like
`=background('yellow')` or `=font_color('yellow')` but couldn't find any. Is there a way I can fill the cell color using functions?

Conditional formatting does not quite work and I hope to be able to find functions or create a function to fill colors.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected result from `I'm looking for functions like =background('yelloe') or =font_color('yellow')`. In order to correctly understand your expected result, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: No need to apologize. I should actually apologize for not providing enough information. For example if I have a cell

"=background('yellow')"

I want this cell to have a yelllow background color. I hope this make sense. Tell me if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.